# Unable to grant any privileges to user in oracle 11gR2 except create session

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I am using oracle database 11g Release 2
I am able to create user and give it create session privileges, but I am unable to give it select privilege.

```
create user user1 identified by pass;
User created.
grant create session to user1;
Grant succeeded.
grant select on emp to user1;
Grant succeeded.
```

After this I connect as user1
Now when I run this statement it say

```
select * from emp;
```

oracle reply=

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Than I checked privileges to user1 using

```
select * from session_privs;
PRIVILEGE
---------------------------------
CREATE SESSION
```

Which means only create session privilege is available to user1. How can I give select privileges to user1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving a use the `SELECT` privilege (or any other privilege for that matter) does not create a synonym. As `user1`, who is **not** the table's owner, you should still reference the table by its fully qualified name, with the owner.
Assuming the owner is called `owner1`, `user1`'s query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM owner1.emp
```

As for the data dictionary query, this is also to be expected. These privileges are recorded in the `[DBA|ALL|USER]_TAB_PRIVS` views:

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_privs WHERE grantee = 'USER1'
```

Comment: More info: If you don't want to specify the owner all the time you can (as hinted above) create a synonym. Owner1 can create a synonym that everyone can use with `CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM emp FOR owner1.emp ;`